# Anyway to stop Apache server from reconnecting?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, apache

I'm sure that due to the server disconnecting and reconnecting, my chat application is being affected. It is supposed to filter messages that are repeated and for the most part does this. However, when two (or more) users that are messaging each other are connected at the same time, their messages seem to repeat. This doesn't happen if only one user is viewing their messages. The application is using the Server-Side Events JavaScript API.

Anyway, is there any way to keep the connection alive? Or a way to work around this? Possibly through server side message filtering?

client-side:

```
function chat() {
    if (document.getElementById('chat').style.display == "none" || document.getElementById('chat').className != "on") {
        if (window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 800px)").matches) {
            document.getElementById('content').className = 'off';
            document.getElementById('chat').className = "on";
            if (document.getElementById('coverPhoto')) {document.getElementById('coverPhoto').className = 'off';}
        } else {
            document.getElementById('chat').style.display = 'block';
        }
        document.getElementById('chatBox').contentDocument.designMode = 'On';
        if (typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
            var source = new EventSource('/ajax/gMessages.php'), last_id, used = {};
            source.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
                var now_id = event.lastEventId;
                if (last_id != now_id && document.getElementById('chatMsgs').innerHTML != event.data) {
                    last_id = event.lastEventId;
                    if (!used[event.data]) {
                        document.getElementById('chatMsgs').innerHTML += event.data;
                        used[event.data] = 1;
                        document.getElementById('chat').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat').scrollHeight; //keep scrollbar at the bottom
                    }
                }   
            }, false);
        } 
    } else if (document.getElementById('chat').style.display == "block" || document.getElementById('chat').className != "off") {
        if (window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 800px)").matches) {
            document.getElementById('content').className = 'on';
            document.getElementById('chat').className = 'off';
            if (document.getElementById('coverPhoto')) {document.getElementById('coverPhoto').className = 'on';}
        } else {
            document.getElementById('chat').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

server-side:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
set_time_limit(0);
include "../includes/config.php"; 
include "../includes/date.php";
function getMessages() {
    $con = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);   
    $con->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); 
    $getMsgs = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `msg_to` = '$_SESSION[username]' AND `type` = '0' ORDER BY `sent` ASC";
    $receivedMsgs = $con->query($getMsgs); 
    foreach ($receivedMsgs->fetchAll() as $msg) { 
        $getUI = "SELECT `profile_pic`, `full_name`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$msg[msg_from]'";
        $uiQuery = $con->query($getUI);
        while ($UI = $uiQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
            echo "id: {$msg['id']}\n"; 
            echo "data: <article>\n"; 
            echo "data: <img src='{$UI[profile_pic]}' alt='{$UI[full_name]}' />\n"; 
            echo "data: <section class='msgCntnt'>\n";
            echo "data: <p class='timeAgo'>". Agotime($msg[sent]) ."</p>\n"; 
            echo "data: <a href='/profile?u={$UI[username]}'>{$UI['full_name']}</a><br />\n"; 
            echo "data: <h4>@{$msg['msg_from']}</h4>\n"; 
            echo "data: <p>{$msg['message']}</p>\n"; 
            echo "data: </section>\n"; 
            echo "data: </article>\n\n"; 
        } 
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(1);
    }
}
getMessages();
?>
```

Comment: Are you using Long Poll or just querying like every five seconds ? I'd suggest using WebSockets but with PHP it's kinda impossible. But still your problem should be somewhere else. Because you shouldn't just insert the message to database but once. Maybe show us some code and tell what is not working.

Comment: @Jompper WebSockets are possible with PHP, but it isn't a very fun experience to develop with.

Comment: Updated OP. I'm using the Server-Sent Events Javascript API. On the right type of server, it works like a simplex WebSockets. On Apache it will reconnect so its long polling on my current server. Anyway, the problem isn't that the messages are being inserted multiple times. They're being output multiple times. And only in the specific situation I talked about in the OP.